code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal])
I'm trying to disconect from a websocket using the unsubscribe method, but I get the same error all the time:

Error 1006 (connection closed abnormally)

This breaks the code and it stops running.
I want to have a code that can subscribe and unsubscribe from a topic and be able to keep running. I've tried to surround the unsubscribe operation with a try..except, but it doesn't work. It also doesn't give any more information on how to do it, and the documentation I've found is not that useful.
This is the code I'm working with right now:
if ws_client is not None:
    try:
        await ws_client.unsubscribe(topic=topic)
            
        print("Successfully unsubscribed and closed WebSocket.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to unsubscribe: {e}")
else:
    print("WebSocket client was not properly initialized.")

Can anyone tell me why I get "Successfully unsubscribed and closed WebSocket" but the code breaks? How should I close the websocket and avoid the 1006 error?
I leave here a small program to reproduce the problem:
    async def main():
    client = WsToken()  # Assuming WsToken is initialized correctly
    spot_order_book = SpotOrderbook.SpotOrderBook() # Assuming SpotOrderBook is initialized correctly
    topic = '/market/level2:BTC-USDT'
    print("Subscribing")
    ws_client = await subscribe_to_spot_topic(client, topic, spot_order_book)
    
    if ws_client is not None:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds before unsubscribing
        print("Unsubscribing")
        await unsubscribe_to_spot_topic(ws_client, topic)
        print("Unsubscribed")
    else:
        print("Failed to create WebSocket client, aborting.")


async def subscribe_to_futures_topic(client, topic, order_book):
    ws_client = await KucoinWsClient.create(None, client, lambda msg: deal_futures_msg(order_book, msg), private=False)
    try:
        await ws_client.subscribe(topic)
        return ws_client
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Encountered an error: {e}")
async def unsubscribe_to_spot_topic(ws_client:KucoinWsClient,topic):
    if ws_client is not None:
        try:
            await ws_client.unsubscribe(topic=topic)
            
            print("Successfully unsubscribed and closed WebSocket.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to unsubscribe: {e}")
    else:
        print("WebSocket client was not properly initialized.")



If you are seeing the "Successfully unsubscribed and closed WebSocket" message being printed, then the problem is clearly not with the unsubscribe operation, since it already finished its work by the time that message is printed. The error has to be coming from somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action.

okay, added the code to the question
